# Programatically show the slide over master view in a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

When using a `UISplitViewController` in portrait mode on an iPad I am given a fullscreen view of my detail view controller which is intended. I can slide from the left and reveal the master view slide over, how can I trigger this slide over programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this it seems, but I have found that using the following code has the intended behaviour:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
  self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryOverlay
})
```

Make sure you set the display mode back to `automatic` on landscape rotation so that it will always show the master and detail like default:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
  super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

  coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {
      self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .automatic
    }
  }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Setting the `preferredDisplayMode` is correct. Setting it in an animation function is brilliant. Very nice.